# UILabel text overlapping with previous text

Tags: ios

[image][image]I am creating a UILabel programatically to display multiple comments. Comments count are not fixed so, I am creating the label using for loop according to number of comments. User can also add comments in the same view and the latest comment added should be displayed on top. But here I am getting issue that, the UILabel text is overlapping with the previous text. 
How should I  update the UILabel programatically.

Please Help. Thanks.

At first showComment is called from viewDidLoad to show initial comments list

```
-(void)showComment{
  for(int i= 0 ;i >fetchCommentArray.count;i++){
   FetchComment *objComment = [fetchCommentArray objectAtIndex:i];
   commentLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CFRectMake(20,moreY,200,100)];
   commentLabel.text = objComment.comment;
   moreY + = 40;
```

}
    }

Now I am calling the ShowComment method when a new comment is added to show new comments.

Comment: Can you share the screen shot of Label overlapping.

Comment: Show some relevant code.

Comment: commentLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,labelY,200,20)];

Comment: @Annu No, update your question with relevant code. That one line is not enough. Post more (in your question, not the comments).

Comment: Ive had your problem too and I found my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320069/text-overlapping-itself-in-table-cells-swift/31320188

Answer (score 1):

Finally done it.

We have to create another label and replace that label with the coordinate of initial label.

```
-(void)setLabel:(NSString *)text{
CGFloat y = 70;
l.text = @"";
for(int i=0;i<5 ;i++){
    l = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, y,100, 21)];
    l.text = text;
   // l.tag = i;
    labelTag = i;
    [self.view addSubview:l];

    y+= 50;
    }

  }
```

// Suppose 5 labels are added on the view using for loop. here CGFloat y = 50; from where the label starts.

```
-(IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender{
NSLog(@">> %d",labelTag);  
for (id viewToRemove in [self.view subviews]){ // This will remove all the labels from the view.
if ([viewToRemove isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]])
[viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:lbl1]; // here lbl1 is another label which we want to show.
}


CGFloat y = 70;
for(int i=0;i<labelTag;i++){
l1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, y,100, 21)];
l1.text = @"text to be changed";
NSLog(@"label text :%@",l1.text);
[self.view addSubview:l1];
y+=50;
}
```

}

// Suppose on button click we want to change the initial text and replace with new text. Thus , using button click method code you can replace label text preventing the overlapping of text.

Answer (score -2):

Rather than programmatically creating the UILabels and then adding it to the UIView using for loop, show your comments using **UITableview**, its rather simple solutions.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I know this. But I have to show the comments content in UILabel. How to do this using UILabel.