# Text overlapping itself in table cells SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have some text which goes into UIlabels I have created inside a table view cell. When these table view cells become updated the text overlaps itself, almost like the previous text what was there has not been removed, like so:

[image]

code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    var nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width * 0.040, cell.frame.size.height * 0.22, cell.frame.size.width * 0.735, cell.frame.size.height * 0.312))

    var userAtIndexPath = finalMatchesBlurUser[indexPath.row]

    nameLabel.text = userAtIndexPath.username.uppercaseString

    cell.addSubview(nameLabel)
}
```

The `finalMatchesBlurUser` is a PFUser fetched from Parses database that will be changing, when this change is what causes the names to overlap.

Can anyone point out why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everytime you update the tableview, it checks the queue to see if it can reuse a cell instead of initializing a new one. In this case, when it updates, it has cells in the queue so you're adding a new label subview everytime the table updates which is causing this effect. In this case, you should only add the label subview if it doesn't exist already. Otherwise, just update the text of that subview.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

         if let nameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel{

              var userAtIndexPath = finalMatchesBlurUser[indexPath.row]

              nameLabel.text = userAtIndexPath.username.uppercaseString
         }
         else{
               nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width * 0.040, cell.frame.size.height * 0.22, cell.frame.size.width * 0.735, cell.frame.size.height * 0.312))

               nameLabel.tag = 100;

               var userAtIndexPath = finalMatchesBlurUser[indexPath.row]

               nameLabel.text = userAtIndexPath.username.uppercaseString

               cell.addSubview(nameLabel)
         }
     return cell;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, understand a bit more now. Is there anyway to check if the UILabel is already been made, like with an if statement?

Comment: based on the way you're doing it, you can loop through the subviews of the cell and check if the label exists and if so just change the text. If not, create the label and assign it a tag value. This tag value will be what you check for when you loop through the cells subviews initally to check for its existence. Make sense?

Comment: Kind of, tag the UILabel and if statement check it via the tag? Can't I just remove the nameLabel from the view removeFromSubview

Comment: mine as well just change the text contents instead of removing it just to re add it again. Hopefully my edit can gain clarification on the logic I was thinking for your example.

Comment: Sorry one more question, this seems to work fine for just the nameLabel, but as you can see in the image I have 2 more labels, which are not working as they are meant to?

Comment: Personally, I would recommend you subclass the table view cell and create a .xib styling it however you would like. Then instead of checking for a labels existence, you can be confident the label is instantiate and just change the contents of the labels as you choose. Check out http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702 for an example of how to subclass

Comment: Thats not what I want to do, I want do everything in code. I've been stuck on this for hours. This is fine for change the nameLabel, but what if I have more then one label inside the table view cell? How do I change all if them????

Answer (score 2):

the UILabel is created every time even when the cell is reused.
A solution is to create the UILabel in Interface Builder and assign a tag (e.g. 100).

Then use this code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let nameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel
    let userAtIndexPath = finalMatchesBlurUser[indexPath.row]
    nameLabel.text = userAtIndexPath.username.uppercaseString
}
```